# How to get custom header values in spring integration gateway?

Tags: spring-integration, custom-headers, spring-integration-http

This is my first question here.

My web application is using spring integration for getting 3rd party APIs response.

The response has custom header values start with 'X-'.
The X-Values are two. (X-AccessToken-Quota-Allotted, X-AccessToken-Quota-Current)

So, I added inboundHeaderNames in header-mapper in config xml as below.

```
    <int-http:outbound-gateway id="dms.put.outbound.gateway.cert"
        header-mapper="dmsHeaderMapper"
       ...
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<bean id="dmsHeaderMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper" factory-method="outboundMapper" >
    <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="X-Request-Id...blabla"/>
    <property name="inboundHeaderNames" value="X-AccessToken-Quota-Allotted, X-AccessToken-Quota-Current"/>
    <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value=""/>
</bean>
```

Below is a response. I can see X-AccessToken-Quota-Allotted & X-AccessToken-Quota-Current in headers attribute.

> [integration] GenericMessage [payload={"type":"commonResponse","serverName":"uslxacd20022use1c.intranet.local","errorMessage":null}, headers={errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@41208186, X-Request-Id=0ce88cd6-d04b-47dc-b3db-224656fe9090, uri=https://api-server.com/blabla, http_statusCode=200, **X-AccessToken-Quota-Allotted=5000**, jsonObjectName=DmsCommonResponseDto, Authorization=Bearer qqdtbhtp5vk2ss69wjpbdfvh, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@41208186, json__TypeId__=class com.blabla.DmsPhoneRequestDto, requestId=0ce88cd6-d04b-47dc-b3db-224656fe9090, **X-AccessToken-Quota-Current=3**, id=12072f4b-8403-a328-6a77-aaba935beba2, contentType=application/json, Content-Type=application/json;charset=UTF-8, timestamp=1592791409206}]

Almost every filed value is mapped to responseDto's fields, but I don't know how to map X-custom header values to responseDto's field.

Below are current settings.

```
<int:gateway id="dmsHttpPUTGateway" service-interface="blabla.gateway.DmsHttpPUTGateway" 
        default-request-channel="dms.put.ch.request.header.router"><int:method name="call" /></int:gateway>

<int:header-value-router input-channel="dms.put.ch.reply.header.router" header-name="jsonObjectName">
    <int:mapping value="DmsCommonResponseDto" channel="dms.put.ch.reply.transformer.DmsCommonResponseDto"/>
</int:header-value-router>

<int:channel id="dms.put.ch.reply.transformer.DmsCommonResponseDto"></int:channel>

<int:json-to-object-transformer input-channel="dms.put.ch.reply.transformer.DmsCommonResponseDto" output-channel="dms.put.ch.reply" type="blabla.DmsCommonResponseDto"></int:json-to-object-transformer>

    DmsCommonResponseDto.java 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String serverName;
private DmsErrorMessageDto errorMessage;
private Date responseDate;

...setter, getter method.
```

Any even little clue would be helpful too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a custom transformer downstream of the json transformer.

```java
class MyTransformer extends AbstractTransformer {

    protected abstract Object doTransform(Message<?> message) {
        DmsCommonResponseDto dto = (DmsCommonResponseDto) message.getPayload();
        dto.setRequestId(message.getHeaders.get("X-request-id"));
        ...
        return dto.
    }    

}
```